# Force wireless card to scan only one channel (programatically)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, wifi

I'm using Wlanapi.dll in Windows (Visual Studio), the default `WlanScan` function always scans for wifi networks in all channels.

Is there a command to nail the wireless card to one wifi-channel? The reason is to speed up the scanning and be more accurate. Filtering the results is not valid.

Comment: How long does the scanning actually take?  And why do you need it to be so fast, as part of the boot sequence it shouldn't that long.

Comment: One full scan to all the 2.4G channels could take up to 3 seconds. Most wifi-adaptors fake this long time by returning very quickly a "draft list" wich has missing items and inaccurate power.

Comment: I forgot to mention, Im coding a program that scans the average power each WIFI channel (individually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been studying and using the MSDN in the last weeks. Even if it is possible to stick the scan to a specific SSID, but however it's not possible to stick it to one channel. You have to filter the results by yourself.

This applies to the native Wlanapi.dll and/or the commonly-used adaptation layer [ManagedWifi](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) by many programs (like [inSSIDer 2](https://github.com/metageek-llc/inSSIDer-2)).  However I can see that the NDIS is another world and thus another question.

Comment: UPDATE 2018:  Solution here, by setting WlanSetInterface function wlan_intf_opcode_media_streaming_mode as defined in the Windows Native Wifi Reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-disable-automatic-scanning-for-wifi/4c8253ec-40c6-42c8-a9f7-00d78fce966c

Answer (score 0):

The reason for having multiple channels is that WiFi will change channels if a particular one is full of noise (from other 2.4Ghz sources: microwave ovens, cordless phones, Bluetooth devices, wireless video cameras, outdoor microwave links, wireless game controllers, Zigbee devices, fluorescent lights, WiMAX, and so on).  Even if you could limit your WiFi card to 1 channel, it would probably stop working pretty quickly because of noise.  I can't remember how often WiFi hops channels, but BlueTooth does it 75 times a second, and any time it decides to use YOUR channel, you lose data.

Comment: In normal scenario (i.e. your home) the Wifi does not hop between channels, it is a static channel of fixed width (20 / 40). The exception is WiFi roaming in large buildings, etc. -- But this is NOT the question asked above.